# Program returns only one Pythagorean triplet

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
a = range(0,1001)
b = range(1,1001)
c = range(2,1001)
d = [(0,0,0)]
for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c) :
  if (x*x) + (y*y) == (z*z) :
    d.append((x,y,z))
    continue
print d
```

output :

```
[(0, 0, 0), (3, 4, 5)]
```

I've found other methods using def and iter but I want to know why this is printing only one triplet.
I'm totally new in this.

Comment: if you print the values like `print x,y,z`, you will see it iterate over all values, nothing wrong with your code, that the only triplet which answer the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49857071/4954037).

a quick fix is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

a = range(0, 1001)
b = range(1, 1001)
c = range(2, 1001)
d = []
for x,y,z in product(a,b,c):
  print(x, y, z)
  if (x*x) + (y*y) == (z*z):
    d.append((x,y,z))
print(d)
```

...this is higly inefficient!

this will be more efficient (not well tested!):

```
from math import sqrt

d = []
for z in range(1, 1001):
    z2 = z**2
    for x in range(1, z//2 + 1):
        x2 = x**2
        y = round(sqrt(z2 - x2))
        if x2 + y**2 == z2:
            d.append((x, y, z))
```

this will have one entry for each triplet only; i.e. only `(3, 4, 5)` will be in the resulting list; `(4, 3, 5)` will not be there - you may add those 'duplicates' separately if you need them...

Comment: Got my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You logic only iterates on a subset of tuples of the form `(x, x+1, x+2)`.

In the ranges you have supplied only `(3, 4, 5)` fits this criterion as well as being a Pythagorean triplet.